# Как срабатывает эта часть css кода?

Tags: css, css3

Увидел в верстке вот такой код, не могу понять как он работает..

```
zoom:1;
display:inline-block;
*display:inline;
color:#fff;
```

Интересует непосредственно 3я строка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Третья строка - CSS-хак для обеспечения адекватного отображения в древних браузерах Internet Explorer версии 7 и старше. Эти браузеры игнорировали синтаксическую ошибку в написании имени параметра, поэтому для них будет действовать `display: inline;`. Для современных браузеров `*display: inline;` является синтаксической ошибкой и данный параметр будет проигнорирован.